# soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am seeing a Soft Lockup issue with Linux 2.6.27.39 running on PPC.
I am new to Linux Kernel stuff and hence I don't know where to start looking.

```
[  435.940577] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 11s! [swapper:0]
[  435.958373] NIP: 8d152a94 LR: 8d14bd4c CTR: 8d14bd28
[  435.973239] REGS: 8090dc30 TRAP: 0901   Not tainted  (2.6.27.39-xCCM)
[  435.992534] MSR: 00029200 <EE,ME><0>  CR: 24022028  XER: 00000030
[  436.010819] TASK = 808ef4c8[0] 'swapper' THREAD: 8090c000<0>
[  436.027824] NIP [8d152a94] pspan_handler+0x4c/0x9a0 [mmap_drv]
[  436.045305] LR [8d14bd4c] mmapdrv_handler+0x24/0x64 [mmap_drv]
[  436.062777] Call Trace:
[  436.070088] [8090dd10] [8d14bd4c] mmapdrv_handler+0x24/0x64 [mmap_drv]<0>
[  436.090445] [8090dd20] [800713f8] _handle_IRQ_event+0x60/0xb8<0>
[  436.108445] [8090dd40] [800714ec] handle_IRQ_event+0x9c/0x15c<0>
[  436.126448] [8090dd60] [80073658] handle_fasteoi_irq+0xb4/0x17c<0>
[  436.144975] [8090dd80] [800053a0] do_IRQ+0x78/0xf4<0>
[  436.160112] [8090dd90] [80010d2c] ret_from_except+0x0/0x18<0>
[  436.177331] [8090de50] [800713f8] _handle_IRQ_event+0x60/0xb8<0>
[  436.195331] [8090de90] [80005294] do_softirq+0x5c/0x60<0>
[  436.211506] [8090dea0] [8003fb6c] irq_exit+0x68/0x88<0>
[  436.227161] [8090deb0] [800053a4] do_IRQ+0x7c/0xf4<0>
[  436.242294] [8090dec0] [80010d2c] ret_from_except+0x0/0x18<0>
[  436.259515] [8090df80] [80008e5c] cpu_idle+0x80/0xf8<0>
[  436.275183] [8090dfa0] [8033efa4] __got2_end+0x7c/0x90<0>
[  436.291358] [8090dfc0] [803d77cc] start_kernel+0x294/0x2f4<0>
[  436.308576] [8090dff0] [800003c0] skpinv+0x2e8/0x324<0>
```

After few more lines of traces...I get oops...

```
[  448.638921] Send_signal: Process 0:swapper has send signal 7 to Me(pltf) 
[  448.659257] print_user_stack:current task_struct pid 0, tgid 0 
[  448.676989] USER Call trace:
[  448.685597]  [8090dff0] PC
[  448.693690] Unable to handle kernel paging request for data at address 0x00029200
[  448.716113] Faulting instruction address: 0x80049e3c
[  448.730979] Oops: Kernel access of bad area, sig: 11 [#1]
[  448.747145] PREEMPT LTT NESTING LEVEL : 0
```

This ultimately resets the Linux board.
I checked for unusual interrupts, semaphore or mutex locks and stuff. But I did not find anything abnormal.
Can anyone point me in a right direction as to how i can pin-point the defect, where to start, the potential culprits etc.

Comment: Deal with the crash first. It's easier. You'll need to configure the kernel to write a dump (kdump) and then open it, get the stack trace and see what's going on. Hopefully, the bug that led to the crash also caused the hang.

Comment: The crash is due to a watchdog expiring...Which will be because of this particular hang...
I will have to pin-down to the cause of this hang first.
And regarding kdump installation, I will not be able to do it since it is a remote system which needs to be up and running 24x7. Only dynamic debugging can be done. [A lot of constraints... I agreee]

Comment: If the watchdog causes an OOPS then the watchdog is buggy.

Comment: I think the reason for oops is different. I think it is trying to print the stack of swapper [process 0 - which cannot be accessed]. 
The key here is to debug why the CPU got stuck in the first place. I am not able to find that out.